# How to kill a thread imported from third-party lib?

Tags: java, multithreading

I import a third-party lib in my project, and now we publish it on Websphere(I use a **ServletContextListener** to clean all the treads in my application, use  **Thread.stop()** method), but everytime we redeploy this app, I found the old thread still alive, I search on internet,and know it shoud use a voilate member or with **interrupt()**, but I don't wanna hack on third-party lib, so who can give me a hint?
thanks:)
third-party lib code as follow:

```
public void run() {
      while (true) {
            try {
                for (DefaultFuture future : FUTURES.values()) {
                    if (future == null || future.isDone()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - future.getStartTimestamp() > future.getTimeout()) {
                        // create exception response.
                        Response timeoutResponse = new Response(future.getId());
                        // set timeout status.
                        timeoutResponse.setStatus(future.isSent() ? Response.SERVER_TIMEOUT : Response.CLIENT_TIMEOUT);
                        timeoutResponse.setErrorMessage(future.getTimeoutMessage(true));
                        // handle response.
                        DefaultFuture.received(future.getChannel(), timeoutResponse);
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.error("Exception when scan the timeout invocation of remoting.", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I make a simple local test, and found **thread.stop()** can stop the thread, and use local jetty, I can reproduce the problem, who can explain it?

my local test code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    myThread t1 = new myThread();
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    t1.stop();
    System.in.read();
}
```

}

```
class myThread extends Thread{
@Override
public void run() {
    int i=0;
    while(true){
        try {
            System.out.println(i++);
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the issue? What problem is this thread causing you?

Comment: Everytime we just redeploy the app, a new thread will be created, I think it may cause some memory leaks

Comment: How do you start this Third Party thread. Seems like it implements Runnable. But do you create and start thread instance yourself or the Third Party API does that?

Comment: There is no way out for the thread in your 3rd party code.the Runnable catch everything and no return called.

Comment: I make a local test, and find __thread.stop()__ can stop this thread, but don't know why on Websphere(jetty as well), thread.stop does not work

Comment: @taoeaten,different JVM may has different reaction to the stop() method

Comment: `thread.stop()` is deprecated. If you don't want to hack the lib, maybe you can run it in a separate process?

Comment: Please, please, please do not call Thread.stop() in production code.  As several others have already said; If the 3rd party lib does not do what you want, then you should either fix it or abandon it and find another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stop method is deprecated. It is unsafe. You should read the Oracle tutorial - [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Refer to the paragraph:

> What should I use instead of Thread.stop? For example, suppose your
>   applet contains the following start, stop and run methods:
>
> ```
> private Thread blinker;
>
> public void start() {
>     blinker = new Thread(this);
>     blinker.start();
> }
>
> public void stop() {
>     blinker.stop();  // UNSAFE!
> }
>
> public void run() {
>     while (true) {
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(interval);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e){
>         }
>         repaint();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You can avoid the use of Thread.stop by replacing the applet's stop and run methods with:
>       private volatile Thread blinker;
>
> ```
> public void stop() {
>     blinker = null;
> }
>
> public void run() {
>     Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
>     while (blinker == thisThread) {
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(interval);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e){
>         }
>         repaint();
>     }
> }
> ```

Why don't you extend the third-party Class, and re-write the thread method?